# Amazon SQS:: Got an error while trying to create queue: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, go, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create Amazon SQS from my local machine and facing errors like

```
Got an error while trying to create queue: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. 
For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

**What I did:**

**Step-1:**
I have set up my credentials in .aws/credentials file

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = TestAccessKey
aws_secret_access_key = TestSecretAccessKey
```

**Step-2:**
My code in go lang like below

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/sqs"
)

func CreateQueue(sess *session.Session, queueName string) (*sqs.CreateQueueOutput, error) {
    sqsClient := sqs.New(sess)
    result, err := sqsClient.CreateQueue(&sqs.CreateQueueInput{
        QueueName: &queueName,
        Attributes: map[string]*string{
            "DelaySeconds":      aws.String("0"),
            "VisibilityTimeout": aws.String("60"),
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result, nil
}

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Profile: "default",
        Config: aws.Config{
            Region: aws.String("us-east-1"),
        },
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Failed to initialize new session: %v", err)
        return
    }

    queueName := "my-new-queue"
    createRes, err := CreateQueue(sess, queueName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Got an error while trying to create queue: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Created a new queue with url: " + *createRes.QueueUrl)
}
```

**Step-3:**

[image]

Comment: Can you try to run that from the command prompt and not from PowerShell? I believe that this issue is connected to the PowerShell.

Comment: I have just tried with Command Prompt, but No luck. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating profile in **Shared Credential File (.aws/credentials)** as below:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=TestAccessKey
aws_secret_access_key=TestSecretAccessKey
region=us-east-1
```

I just added region at the end.

Comment: I have just added a region in my credentials file. But no luck. Any other idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65341062/1273882 This may help!

Answer (score 1):

To verify if your CLI session has correct AWS credentials configured run this command `aws sts get-caller-identity` This command will show which profile is used. If this works fine then you can run any simple AWS commands something like `S3.getBuckets()` to verify if the dev environment is setup correctly.

These 2 solutions should give you enough input to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Gives me `Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".` which helped for this command but not the original problem